# Not sure to VLOOKUP or IF formula and if this is possible

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have 2 Excel worksheets, both have one row that contains a name and in another row contains an access card number. They both contain the same names but the card numbers are different (one worksheet for building access and one worksheet for parking access).  I would like to use a formula that would take the names from the parking card worksheet and IF it matches the name in the building card worksheet then place the parking card code next to it.  My Excel knowledge is quite poor but I did try to figure out an IF and VLOOKUP formula but it seems like it would be a combination of both.

Comment: You can use Vlookup, can you show some example?

Comment: You don't need IF, just a lookup.  The complication is that the data isn't on the same row.  You are looking for the matching name, and then taking the card code from the next row.  VLOOKUP won't handle that (needs to be on the same row).  You can do this with INDEX plus MATCH.  MATCH will find the name.  INDEX will select the value you need.  Typical use is to select from the same row in another column.  In this case, you would select from the same column in the resulting row+1.

Comment: I think this makes sense.  The card number and name are on the same row, the card number is in column A and the name is next to it in column B, this is the same for both worksheets, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but I **think** the solution could be a multi-criteria index match (which is like a vlookup, but superior for a few reasons). Here's [instructions on how to do it](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/).

You can always add it into an if statement, but I think a multi-criteria index match would fit the bill.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This problem is a single criterion (name), so a multi-criteria match wouldn't be necessary (although index/match would still be an alternative to vlookup).  In general, though, answers should be a self-contained solution.  External links can break, in which case this would be just a hint.  Include the essential information in the answer and use the link for attribution and reference.  With a little more rep, you would be able to post helpful guidance and a link in a comment.